# Am I installing Ubuntu correctly?

Tags: usb-installation

I am going through the Ubuntu installation (onto a USB) and I'm going through the standard steps, installing alongside Windows Boot Manager. Here's the page I'm on right now.

[image: Partitioning screenshot]

This was setup by the installation, and I have moved the divider as I like.
My current selection isn't going to overwrite ANY of my old files, correct?

Comment: Clarify your disk partitions and provide more details. Information provided by you is not detailed enough to help you out.

Comment: Yes, it looks OK for an automatic install.

Comment: I highly recommend following a tutorial for Ubuntu installation before you commit any changes to disk. It can prevent any plausible risk i.e loss of data.

Answer (score 2):

Select `/dev/sda5` for ubuntu and it should be fine. If you are not very comfortable with Ubuntu or new to it, it may be better to use Windows disk management utilities to create all the necessary partitions.

Comment: Edit: yes, under Files it says /dev/sda4 (ntfs) and under Ubuntu it says  /dev/sda5 (ext4). So I'm ok?